# Univocity CSV : Missing quotes after parsing

Tags: csv, univocity

I am trying to parse a CSV with Quotes using Univocity CSV, I find that after parsing the close quotes are missing from some values.

```
CSV:
ACCT,NAME,AGE,ADDRESS
700,GINI,23,"AB,ECITY-1"
800,HANNAH,30,"AB,ECITY-1"
900,IAN,40,"XYZ,ECITY-1"
1900,LYDIA,40,"XYZ,ECITY-1"
```

Output:

```
[GINI, "AB,ECITY-1]
[HANNAH, "AB,ECITY-1]
[IAN, "XYZ,ECITY-1]
[LYDIA, "XYZ,ECITY-1]



CsvParserSettings settings = new CsvParserSettings();
settings.getFormat().setLineSeparator("\n");
settings.setKeepQuotes(true);
settings.setQuoteDetectionEnabled(false);
settings.trimValues(true);
settings.excludeFields(excludeHeaders.split("ACCT,AGE"));
CsvParser baseFileParser = new CsvParser(settings);
String[] baseRow;
baseFileParser.beginParsing(baseFile);
while((baseRow = baseFileParser.parseNext())!= null){
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(baseRow));
}
```

What am I missing. Why is the close quote missing in the output?

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer myslef.. Had to remove the below line

```
settings.getFormat().setLineSeparator("\n");
```

Code works fine if the above line is removed

Answer (score 0):

Are you using version 2.5.8? If not then this looks related to [a bug](https://github.com/uniVocity/univocity-parsers/issues/197) I fixed recently. Just update and it will work.

A little explanation:

In your case the bug will manifest itself if you set `settings.getFormat().setLineSeparator("\n");` but the input file has `\r\n` as the separator. The `\r` will he handled by the parser as a whitespace and trigger the bug.

That's why removing `settings.getFormat().setLineSeparator("\n");` worked for you - if you are on Windows, the default line separator used by the parser will be `\r\n`. This will avoid the bug as there is no trailing whitespace before the line ending.